# Sub select & union all

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT C.ClientCaseNumber,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId IN (28, 29, 30) THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS [Wezwania],
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId IN (14, 21) THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS [Kontakt],
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 32 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS [SMS],
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 44 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS [Zgon],
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 49 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS [Areszt],
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 37 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS [Odmowa],
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 39 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS [Podważa],
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 99 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS [Ugoda],
       [Adres],
       [Numer],
       [Mail],
       [Powód]
FROM   (SELECT Notes AS [Adres]
        FROM   CaseActionHistory
        WHERE  CaseActionDefinitionId = 68
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Info AS [Numer]
        FROM   CaseActionHistory
        WHERE  CaseActionDefinitionId IN (54, 55, 56, 58,
                                          59, 60, 61, 62, 63)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Notes AS [Mail]
        FROM   CaseActionHistory
        WHERE  CaseActionDefinitionId = 66
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Description AS [Powód]
        FROM   CaseActionDefinition
               JOIN CaseActionHistory AS C
                 ON DefinitionId = C.CaseActionDefinitionId
        WHERE  DefinitionId BETWEEN 70 AND 78) AS x
       INNER JOIN CaseDetails AS C
               ON x.CaseDetailId = C.CaseDetaislId
       INNER JOIN CaseActionHistory AS CA
               ON C.CaseDetailsId = CA.CaseDetailId
WHERE  C.ClientId = '11'
GROUP  BY C.ClientCaseNumber
```

I've got such query. As return shows error of invalid columns "CaseDetailId, CaseDetailsId, Mail, Numer, Powód".

---

http://oi39.tinypic.com/2vwy44n.jpg

That's more or less how the results should look like.

ClientCaseNumber is taken from table CaseDetails
All the sums are sums of code added to CaseActionHistory table.
Notes/Info are in CaseActionHistory table
Description is placed in CaseActionDefinition table.

Between tables there are such connections:

CaseDetails.CaseDetailId = CaseActionHistory.CaseDetailsId

CaseActionHistory.CaseActionDefinitionId = CaseActionDefinition.DefinitionId

Comment: Are the columns really exist? show us your table schema please

Comment: There is no selected `x.CaseDetailId` form the subquery with the alias `x`.

Answer (score 2):

The `UNION` clause does not work like that.

This query:

```
select Notes as [Adres] from CaseActionHistory where ...
UNION ALL
select Info as [Numer] from CaseActionHistory where ...
UNION ALL
select Notes as [Mail] from CaseActionHistory where ...
UNION ALL
select Description as [Powód] from CaseActionDefinition join CaseActionHistory ...
```

will not populate a table with 4 columns. Instead it will be a table with one column, with all the values one after the other. The name of the column will be taken from the first `SELECT`, i.e.

- if the first query returns values 1 and 2,
- the second query returns values 3 and 4
- the third query returns values 5 and 6
- the fourth query returns values 7 and 8

you wont get:

```
Adres  | Numer | Mail | Powód
------------------------------
    1  |     3 |    5 |     7
    2  |     4 |    6 |     8
```

but you'll get:

```
Adres  
-------
    1  
    2  
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
```

Comment: Any idea how to pass it? Cause I have to SELECT exactly those rows from database and connect them with sums above. And I don't have any idea how to make it..

Comment: I cannot infer what you are trying to do from the code. Please try to explain what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: My guess OP needs to add the columns in increasing ordinal position, using NULLs as placeholders - e.g. `SELECT something, NULL, NULL UNION SELECT NULL, something2, NULL UNION SELECT NULL, NULL, something3` aliasing in the first part of the union select statement to the correct column names.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2mzcv4h&s=5

System works like => add action "Found mail" and in note type the Mail that's why retriving Note is necessary. Same goes for Phone number however it's put in "Info". [Powód] works like adding a code with definition which is specified in another table so the definition itself has to be retrived. First 3 columns in report after CaseClientNumber are sums of actions added to Case connected with sending mails, making phone calls etc.

Comment: http://oi39.tinypic.com/2vwy44n.jpg

That's more or less how the results should look like.

ClientCaseNumber is taken from table CaseDetails
All the sums are sums of code added to CaseActionHistory table.
Notes/Info are in CaseActionHistory table
Description is placed in CaseActionDefinition table.

Between tables there are such connections:

CaseDetails.CaseDetailId = CaseActionHistory.CaseDetailsId
CaseActionHistory.CaseActionDefinitionId = CaseActionDefinition.DefinitionId

Answer (score 0):

Are you not missing the alias 'x' from these fields:

```
SELECT
C.ClientCaseNumber
,sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId in (28,29,30) then 1 else 0 end) as [Wezwania]
,sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId in (14,21) then 1 else 0 end) as [Kontakt]
,sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 32 then 1 else 0 end) as [SMS]
,sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 44 then 1 else 0 end) as [Zgon]
,sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 49 then 1 else 0 end) as [Areszt]
,sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 37 then 1 else 0 end) as [Odmowa]
,sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 39 then 1 else 0 end) as [Podważa]
,sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 99 then 1 else 0 end) as [Ugoda]
,x.[Adres]
,x.[Numer]
,x.[Mail]
,x.[Powód]

FROM
(select Notes as [Adres] from CaseActionHistory where CaseActionDefinitionId = 68
UNION ALL
select Info as [Numer] from CaseActionHistory where CaseActionDefinitionId in (54,55,56,58,59,60,61,62,63)
UNION ALL
select Notes as [Mail] from CaseActionHistory where CaseActionDefinitionId = 66
UNION ALL
select Description as [Powód] from CaseActionDefinition join CaseActionHistory as C on DefinitionId = C.CaseActionDefinitionId where DefinitionId between 70 and 78) 
AS x

inner join CaseDetails as C on x.CaseDetailId = C.CaseDetaislId
inner join CaseActionHistory as CA on C.CaseDetailsId = CA.CaseDetailId

where C.ClientId = '11'

GROUP by C.ClientCaseNumber
```

Comment: Adding "x.CaseDetailsId" shows error about queries must having the same ammount of results.